# $A^4=-1.6A^2-0.64I $ then find the $ \lim_{m\to\infty}{A^m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

I was trying the following problem
$A^4=-1.6A^2-0.64I $ then find the $$ \lim_{m\to\infty}{A^m}$$
I tried following
$ (A^4)^2 = (1.6 A^2 +  0.64I)^2 $ and $A^6 = 
(1.6 A)^2 + (1.6) (0.64) I -0.64 I $. I am unable to catch the pattern for powers of $A$ so that i can find the value of limit. Answer of this question is zero. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a different, "spectral" proof. Note that it is easy to extract information about *eigenvalues* from the polynomial identity you are starting with. Each (complex) eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ must satisfy

$$\lambda^4+1.6\lambda^2+0.64=(\lambda^2+0.8)^2=0.$$

which means that all eigenvalues of $A$ are square roots of $-0.8$. In particular, the *spectral radius* of $A$ is smaller than 1. It turns out there is a direct relation between the spectral radius and the convergence of the powers of $A$. You can have a look at [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence) on Wikipedia. The direction we are interested in involves Jordan normal form.